# Laravel Eloquent - how to get only 2 child of each parent using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get category with only 2 subcategory not all subcategory. Like below output

```
Category 1
  subcategory 1, 
  subcategory 2,
Category 2
  subcategory 1,
  subcategory 2, 
Category 3
  subcategory 1,
  subcategory 2
```

Total 5 category and each category have 5 subcategory

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model {
    public function subcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }

    public function limitSubcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory')->limit(2);
    }
}
```

Subcategory.php

```
class Subcategory extends Model {
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

HomeController.php

Method 1:

```
Category::with(['limitSubcategory' => function($query) {

}])->get();
```

Method 2:

```
Category::with(['subcategory' => function($query) {
   $query->limit(2);
}])->get();
```

But it get only 2 subcategory in first category.

[Click here to view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5UvY.jpg)

Please help me, How to get?

Comment: You can do something like this: `$categories = Category::all(); $categories->each(function($c) {$c->load(['subcategory' => function($q) {$q->limit(2);}]);})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the trait: HasEagerLimit:

you can install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

and then in your model:

```
class Category extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

    public function subcategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
    }

public function limitSubcategory(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory')->limit(2);
}
}
```

and also in SubCategory model:

```
class Category extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

now : when you load your relation ... it should return the result you desire:

```
$results=Category::with('limitSubcategory')->get();
```

more details in:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 0):

In your controller when you retreive Category like this `$categ = Category::all()` you can have your limited list with `$categ->limit_subcategory`

If you want to optimise request with eager loading and not have N+1 problem in sql request you can do `$categ = Category::whth(['limitSubcategory']->get()`

Read this part of documentation for more informations about eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading